# Matlab: replace element in matrix by the minimum of the row excluding itself

Tags: matlab, matrix, minimum

I want to replace each element by the minimum of its row, other than the element itself.

Example: input `In = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]`, output `out = [2 1 1; 5 4 4; 8 7 7]`

EDIT: without `for` loop, unless computationally more efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it with two calls to `min`. you can do similarly with `sort(In,2)`:

```
% input matrix
In = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
% compute minimum for each row
[val,mincols] = min(In,[],2);
% generate matrix made of minimum value of each row
Out = repmat(val,[1 size(In,2)]);
% find indexes of minimum values
minrows = 1:size(In,1);
minidxs = sub2ind(size(In),minrows,mincols');
% replace minimum values with infs
In(minidxs) = inf;
% find next minimum values
val = min(In,[],2);
% set original minimum elements to next minimum values
Out(minidxs) = val
```

Comment: [**`'`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html) is not transpose. [**`.'`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) is

Comment: i can be sure that my *indexes* are real numbers so it's practically the same

Comment: @SardarUsama Well said :-)

Comment: tough... :) I took the note.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a new function [`movmin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movmin.html) introduced in MATLAB R2016a to solve this with a moving minimum:

```
In = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];  % Sample data
C = size(In, 2);             % Get the number of columns
out = movmin(In(:, [2:C 1:(C-1)]), [0 C-2], 2, 'Endpoints', 'discard')

out =

     2     1     1
     5     4     4
     8     7     7
```

The above works by first indexing the columns of `In` to create wrap-around copies of the matrix, then slides a window of size `C-1` along each row, computing the minimum. The `'Endpoints', 'discard'` option discards results where the window extends past the edges of the matrix.